# Are 90% of Middle Eastern refugees on food stamps in the United States?

Tags: united-states, refugees

According to [Never Again Canada](http://www.neveragaincanada.ca/90-percent-middle-eastern-refugees-food-stamps/):

> More than 90 percent of recent refugees from Middle Eastern nations are on food stamps and nearly 70 percent receive cash assistance, according to government data.
>
> According to Office of Refugee Resettlement (ORR) data highlighted by the immigration subcommittee staff of Sen. Jeff Sessions (R-AL)— chairman of the Subcommittee on Immigration and the National Interest — in FY 2013, 91.4 percent of Middle Eastern refugees (accepted to the U.S. between 2008-2013) received food stamps, 73.1 percent were on Medicaid or Refugee Medical Assistance and 68.3 percent were on cash welfare.

Are those figures accurate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The best source of information is [OFFICE OF REFUGEE RESETTLEMENT
ANNUAL REPORT TO CONGRESS FY 2014](https://www.acf.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/orr/orr_annual_report_to_congress_fy_2014_signed.pdf).

According to table Table II-22: Public Assistance Utilization by Selected Refugee Groups by Year of Survey:

The percent of Middle East refugees receiving SNAP assistance was:

2014:  89.7
2013:  91.4
2012:  89.2
2011:  87.8
2010:  82.0
2009:  93.1

[image]

The data for each survey-year include a five-year window, in other words this is about refugees who have arrived in the past five years.

The table also provides percentages of refugees receiving housing assistance, Medicaid, and "cash assistance".

Comment: Should be noted that data over represents new arrivals.

Comment: Why is Eastern Europe on the table if there's no relevant data?

Comment: @ventsyv however it seems that Latin American refugees are 50% less dependent on food stamps, despite the same dataset